# ¿Cómo paso valores de tipo int de diferentes metodos, a uno solo?

Tags: java

Esta es la común y corriente de la cual ya tengo conocimiento

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Duda{
  public static void main (String[] args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática:");
   int nota = sc.nextInt();
   pass(nota);
   }

  static void pass(int PassedNota){
   System.out.println("La nota del estudiante es" + PassedNota);
  }
}
```

> Pero lo que deseo es que diferentes variables vayan a un método central el cual va a promediar estas notas. Algo así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Duda{
  public static void main (String[] args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática: ");
   int NotaUno = sc.nextInt();
   pass(NotaUno);
   MetodoDos();
   }


  static void MetodoDos (){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en física: ");
   int NotaDos = sc.nextInt();
   pass(NotaDos);
   MetodoTres();
  }

  static void MetodoTres (){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en ciencias naturales: ");
   int NotaTres = sc.nextInt();
   pass(NotaTres);
   pass();
  }

  static void pass(int PassedNotaUno, int PassedNotaDos, int PassedNotaTres){
   String [] array = {"mate","fisica","ciencias"};
   int promedio = (PassedNotaUno + PassedNotaDos + PassedNotaTres)/nom.length;
   System.out.println("El promedio del estudiante es" + promedio);
  }

}
```

Comment: Esto es un planteamiento pésimo. Si son 50 notas ¿vas a tener 50 métodos? ¿Y si son 1,000 notas de todo el historial? ¿1,000 métodos? Con que guardes la información en un sólo array o en un mapa con pares como: `Física, 80`, `Mates, 90`, `Materia99999, 100` es suficiente. Tienes un solo objeto que representa el estado general del estudiante y **no 9999 métodos que hacen lo mismo con valores distintos** ¡La POO existe precisamente para evitar eso que quieres hacer! Recuerda una norma básica en POO: no repitas una y otra vez código que hace lo mismo, reutiliza tus objetos y sus métodos.

Comment: Tranquilo, que yo solo pregunto estas cosas para adquirir conocimientos, obviamente nunca  las aplicaría así pero en un algún caso de mi vida como programador tendré que aplicar, soy un jóven de 13 años con curiosidad y nada más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Que tal? Vamos al grano, como te explica el compañero de forma un poco agresiva en el comentario, el cual tienen razón, necesitamos usar POO que es el objectivo principal de java, usar java de modo imperativo es estupido y aunque se puede usar no esta diseñado para eso.

Para facilitarte el ejemplo vamos a crear una clase que se llamará asignatura, esa clase va a tener asociado un nombre y una nota, la clase tambien va a tener un metodo que pida por teclado el numero que espera por consola, como en tu ejemplo:

```
public class Asignatura {

    private String nombre;
    private int nota;

    public Asignatura(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nota = 0;
    }

    public void setNota(int nota) throws Exception{
        if(nota >= 0) {
            this.nota = nota;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Nota negativa");
        }
    }

    public int getNota() {
        return this.nota;
    }

    public void askNota() throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en " + this.nombre + ":");
       this.setNota(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Luego en la clase main crearemos dos funciones una que pregunte la nota y otra que haga la media:

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String [] array = {"mate","fisica","ciencias"};
      Asignatura [] asignaturas = new Asignatura[array.length];
      for(int i=0; i < array.length ;i++){
          asignaturas[i] = new Asignatura(array[i]);
      }

      takeNumbers(asignaturas);
      float average = makeAverage(asignaturas);
      System.out.println(average);
    }

    private static float makeAverage(Asignatura[] asignaturas) {
        int result = 0;
        for (Asignatura asignatura : asignaturas) {
            result += asignatura.getNota();
        }

        return (float) result/asignaturas.length;
    }

    private static void takeNumbers(Asignatura[] asignaturas) {
        for (Asignatura asignatura : asignaturas) {
            try {
                asignatura.askNota();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este main creará n clases asignaturas, les preguntará la nota, hará la media y la mostrará en pantalla.* Y con esto tendrías un ejemplo basico del uso de POO en java, como te explique al principio, en java lo normal es usar POO y no usar programación imperativa, para eso hay otros lenguajes como C o python (tambien tiene POO) que se adecuan mas a el uso de este tipo de programación.

Saludos!!

***NOTA: En el caso que la nota sea menor que 0, lanzará una excepción**

Comment: +1 Buena respuesta. Mi comentario en la pregunta no tenía intención de ser agresivo, sino de ampliar el horizonte de la POO. Sólo añadir que, en un modelo más acabado y más real, habrá una clase `Estudiante` que tendrá entre sus miembros una lista de objetos del tipo `Asignatura`, donde se podrán guardar todas las asignaturas de un solo estudiante de cualquier semestre o período. Y si es un modelo en el que puede haber un estudiante haciendo varias `Carreras` se seguirían creando modelos relacionados y la clase `Asignatura` tendría un nuevo miembro del tipo `Carrera` y así sucesivamente...

Comment: Gracias amigo gracias a tí y otras personas puedo seguir ampliando mis conocimientos teniendo apenas 13 años.
Posdata: Solo pregunte eso por curiosidad de ahí si tengo claro que es POO; algo me dice que algún día tendré que aplicar esto :)

Comment: Si eres tan nuevo como dices, te recomiendo que aprendas java a traves de un curso y no por autodidactica, Java es un lenguaje complicado y dificil de entender sin ayuda. Si estas dando tus pinitos en la programación tirate a python o javascript, son lenguajes mucho mas amigables y con muchisimo potencial

Answer (score 0):

Similar a lo que tratas de realizar, puedes llamar un método en el cual se actualice el valor de cada nota y este a su vez llame el método que realice el promedio:

```
pass(valor, PassedNotaDos, PassedNotaTres);
```

De esta forma al introducir cada valor se va realizando el promedio.

Simplemente tienes que definir variables de clase en las cuales se almacenen los valores de las notas:

```
 private static int PassedNotaUno, PassedNotaDos, PassedNotaTres;
```

este sería el código:

```
class Duda{

  private static int PassedNotaUno, PassedNotaDos, PassedNotaTres;

  public static void main (String[] args){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en matemática: ");
   int NotaUno = sc.nextInt();
   passUno(NotaUno);   
   MetodoDos();
   }


  static void MetodoDos (){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en física: ");
   int NotaDos = sc.nextInt();
   passDos(NotaDos);  
   MetodoTres();
  }

  static void MetodoTres (){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Ingrese la nota del estudiante en ciencias naturales: ");
   int NotaTres = sc.nextInt();
   passTres(NotaTres);
  }


  static void passUno(int valor){     
      pass(valor, PassedNotaDos, PassedNotaTres);
  }

  static void passDos(int valor){     
      pass(PassedNotaUno, valor, PassedNotaTres);
  }

  static void passTres(int valor){     
      pass(PassedNotaUno, PassedNotaDos, valor);
  }


  static void pass(int PassedNotaUno, int PassedNotaDos, int PassedNotaTres){
   String [] array = {"mate","fisica","ciencias"};
    Duda.PassedNotaUno = PassedNotaUno;
    Duda.PassedNotaDos = PassedNotaDos;
    Duda.PassedNotaTres = PassedNotaTres;
   int promedio = ((Duda.PassedNotaUno + Duda.PassedNotaDos + Duda.PassedNotaTres) / array.length);
   System.out.println("El promedio del estudiante es: " + promedio);
  }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.